# Is this function in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Consider the function $F_k: t\in\mathbb{R} \mapsto F_k t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
F_k t = \begin{cases}
0 &\hbox{ if } t\leq k\\
t - k &\hbox{ if } t > k
\end{cases}.
$$
Is this a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ function?

About me the correct answer is no. Surely $F$ is continuous, but it is not the same for its first derivative. As well, I think it has not a compact support, isn't it?

Could anyone please correct me if I am missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: I agree with you on everything

Comment: @purple thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $k \in \mathbb{R}$, the function is continuous without compact support, but as you said it is not even differenti able at $t=k$.

In these cases, to be sure, try to compute the derivatives in the intervals in which the function admits one. See that since the derivative on the right to $k$ is constantly 1, then it cannot go to $0$ approaching $k$ (You can smooth it out, but this is another problem).